# Get the URI of a jQuery UI tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I tried to reload a particular jQuery UI tab with this code

```
var currentTab = $("div#tabs").tabs('option', 'selected');
$('div#tabs').tabs('load', currentTab);
```

and it didn't work, but it works when I change the URI

```
$('div#tabs').tabs('url', currentTab, 'example_page.html').tabs('load', currentTab);
```

But the URI of the tabs keep changing (I have buttons that let the user go to another page), so I can't use a pre-determined URI.

I need to know how I can get the URI of a particular tab. I've searched a lot, and found some solutions, some right here on SO, but none of them work. I'm using the latest version of jQuery and jQuery UI, and can't switch to an older version as I need the "Button" UI Widget Plugin

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you mean "next" / "previous" buttons for each tab content?

Comment: Please don't tell me I need to make an array to store the URIs of the tabs and update it every time a tab is selected, I'm sure jQuery has a built-in solution.

Comment: @pharalia  No, I just need to reload a tab, but to do that I need the current URI of the tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the hash of the anchors

```
$('.jquery-ui-tabs li a').each(function() {

   var hash = this.hash;

});
```

Comment: Oops, I spoke too soon. It doesn't work if the URI of the tab is changed after it is created.